# Android C2DM captcha missing error

Tags: android, android-c2dm

tI have tried this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#sourcecode

and when I connect with my "server" app, which should display registered devices, I got error=Captcha required:

> 08-31 10:31:15.439: ERROR/HttpResponse(745): CaptchaToken=xxx...xxx
>   08-31 10:31:15.439: ERROR/HttpResponse(745): CaptchaUrl=Captcha?xxx...xxx
>   08-31 10:31:15.445: ERROR/HttpResponse(745): Error=CaptchaRequired
>
> 08-31 10:31:15.445: ERROR/HttpResponse(745): Url=https://www.google.com/accounts/ErrorMsg?xxx...xxx

When I got this response, I should somehow display the captcha and interact with it and display registered users again. Do you know how it could by done? Do I need to enter captcha manually each time or only for the first time?

Thanks

Hmyzak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The captcha is displayed when logins have failed. If you get the authentication done correctly, you won't ever see this.

Comment: i am facing the same problem, and my login details are correct. What could the problem be?